# Why page not working after putting valid user check?

Tags: php

i want to protect a page with a user script and after putting this 4 lines of code, login system works, but i received many Undefined index and Undefined offset errors and any class.

it's like that Require_once and include not working at same.

Image of the error:

[image]

```
<?php
  define("_WOJO", true);
  require_once("../../init.php");
  if (!Membership::is_valid([1]))
  Url::redirect(SITEURL);// back to login screen when not valid user
?>


// begin of code when valid user (1)



<?php

define("FLG_CFG", TRUE);
include("inc/config.php");


##################################################
# page configuration
$page['title'] = 'Nog te factureren';
##################################################
# table
$sql['table'] = 'woningopdrachten';
//$sql['joins'][] = 'JOIN company ON company.id_company = user.id_company';
# fields array(column, alias, asc/desc, type, responsive, hidden)
$sql['fields'][] = array('woningopdrachten.id', 'id');
$sql['fields'][] = array('woningopdrachten.makelaar', 'makelaarr', true);
$sql['fields'][] = array('woningopdrachten.adres', 'adres', true);
$sql['fields'][] = array('woningopdrachten.plaats', 'plaats', true);
$sql['fields'][] = array('woningopdrachten.pakket', 'pakket', true);
$sql['fields'][] = array('woningopdrachten.datum', 'datum', true);
//$sql['fields'][] = array('woningopdrachten.status', 'status', true);
//

//$sql['fields'][] = array('woningopdrachten.id', 'view');
//$sql['fields'][] = array('woningopdrachten.id', 'afsluiten');
//$sql['fields'][] = array('woningopdrachten.id', 'datumaanpas');
//$sql['fields'][] = array('woningopdrachten.id', 'delete');


# extras
$sql['groupby'] = false;
$sql['new'] = false;
# delete handler
check_delete();
##################################################
# header
include('div/header.php');
# table
# Filter op (laat enkel opdrachten zien waarvan nog een bon gemaakt moet worden#
//$sql['filters'][] = array('woningopdrachten.status = :woningopdrachten.status', ':woningopdrachten.status', 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql['filters'][] = array('woningopdrachten.status LIKE :status', ':status', "%factureren%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
grid($sql);
# footer
include('div/footer.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say specifically without looking at the other files, but there shouldn't be any issue caused by using multiple requires/includes on the same page.

Where you are getting the undefined index/offset errors, you can use something like var_dump() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php or print_r() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php to get more information about those variables and see what is contained in them vs. what you are expecting to be there.